# DataTables search functionality not working when combined with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, datatables

I'm populating tbody using ng-repeat and later initializing dataTables on the table using a directive as can be seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnzY9/).

```
test.directive("jqTable", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("assignments", function (value) {//I change here
            var val = value || null;            
            if (val)
                element.dataTable({"bDestroy": true});
        });
    };
});
```

DataTable is getting initialized and rendering properly but the search functionality is not working. There are no warnings or errors in the console. Can anyone help me identify what the issue is and how to get the search functionality working on the datatable?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? No matches, or nothing happening when typing in the search box?

Comment: @DanielB No matches. Try search on the dataTable in the jsfiddle I noted in my question.